# Rails 3: Redirecting only specific users to new application while others should be able to access old application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

My employer got new website and wants me to redirect old website(in Rails 3) users to new website whenever customers try to access old website . 
Tricky part is that they want their internal staff to continue to access old website with same URL. But when outside customer comes on old website, 
they want to redirect him/her to new website.

Is this possible?

What I can think of adding “staff” keyword at end of URL, if incoming URL in application controller has “staff” keyword then I can allow internal staff to 
access old website. If incoming URL does not have “staff” keyword in URL, then i can redirect to new website.

Does this make sense?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Or you can assign a subdomain to your website. So, if someone accesses `staff.website.com`, they continue using it. Anyone accessing `website.com` you redirect them.

Comment: Yes, this can be an option. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

sample url: xyz.com?role=staff

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_customer

  protected

  def redirect_if_customer
    if request.host.eql? 'xyz.com' && request.params[:role].eql? 'staff'
      redirect_to "abc.com", status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But Issue with this approach is that every time internal staff members have to attach role = staff at end of URL. Do you agree on this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about which web server your application is using. But this kind of scenario can be achieved in web server instead of app.

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/redirect-urls-with-the-apache-web-server/